# Rotate Animation Does Not Work Properly After View Position Changed Dynamically

Tags: java, android, android-animation

I have added dynamic image views at x,y position in frame layout and I am applying rotate animation after adding views to layout but rotate animation not working properly. It is taking wrong pivot point and rotating around it.

Same animation works fine if views are added static in layout.

Any suggestion?

Comment: post some code please

Answer (score 0):

After your animation completes set your animation property to `fillAfter` to `true`

P.S. Animation only animates the view and does not updates its position on the screen. So in reality you view after animation is at the same place which it was before animation.

Comment: You are right @Murtaza. But the question here is when I change the original position of view by setting setX and setY. the animation not works perfectly.